# Check element class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

This should be a quickie!

I need to differentiate between two elements on click by their class name.. for example

html:

```
<p class='p1'>paragraph element</p>
<p class='p2'>paragraph element</p>
```

jquery:

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class', 'p1') {
        callThisFunction();
    } else {
        doNothing();
    }
});
```

Comment: The other answers provided exactly what you asked, but I think what you're trying to do requires a different approach. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($(this).is(".p1")) {
```

or

```
if ($(this).hasClass("p1")) {
```

`$(this).attr("class", "p1")` actually *sets* the class attribute.  Checking against `$(this).attr("class")` is no good either because it could have multiple classes.

Comment: I was just about to answer with `hasClass` when i saw your answer change, was wondering why no one had ppointed it out sooner! lol

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).hasClass('p1')` is faster.

Comment: you could also fallback to vanilla javascript and do `if ( this.className.match(/\bp1\b/) )`. `\b` being boundary (spaces, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to check the class.

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('p1')) {
        callThisFunction();
    } else {
        doNothing();
    }
});
```

working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nSMDA/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('p1')) {
        console.log("do something");
    } else {
        console.log("do nothing");
    }
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DNKUX/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to differentiate behavior like this- where only some elements take action - what you should really be doing is only binding to the ones that match rather than to every `<p>` element.

```
$('p.p1').on('click', callThisFunction);
```

Here is a new fork of goma's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4b8Pf/2/

Answer (score 0):

`if($(this).attr('class') === 'p1'){}` is what you want to use. `$(this).attr('class', 'p1')` sets the current element to have a class of `p1`.